# Convert raw diff file to colorized html output

Tags: svn, diff

Does anyone know of a script that can accept a raw diff file and pretty print HTML output (which would be easier to review/mail)? A google search returned me some results like http://kafka.fr.free.fr/diff2html/

However all of these scripts require two files as input (they don't even accept two directories). My diff output is the diff between two svn branches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally used [diff2html.py](http://wiki.droids-corp.org/articles/d/i/f/Diff2html.html) to create static html output of a side-by-side diff, given my unified diff intput

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested to [`cdiff`](https://github.com/ymattw/cdiff), a term based tool to display **side by side**, **incremental**, and **colorful** diff, the design is exactly to take unified diff from stdin or revision controlled workspace.

You can just send raw diff for review if your peer is using `cdiff` too.

PS: I am the author of [coderev](http://code.google.com/p/coderev/) and cdiff, I know cdiff is better in both design and quality :)

Answer (score 3):

I've just found [coderev](http://code.google.com/p/coderev/). This might worth a try...

Comment: I recently used coderev and found it very easy to use. The html output gave many different view options for the diffs. Check out the demo site that the dev has put up.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a syntax highlighter, e.g. [pygments](http://pygments.org/) handles diffs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for me is **aha** (Ansi HTML Adapter - https://github.com/theZiz/aha)

```
$ svn diff | colordiff | aha > /tmp/diff.html
```

Answer (score 0):

With the evolution of diff and the existence of "aha", it's pretty simple now.

`diff -y --color=always input1.tsv input2.tsv | aha --black > output.html`

I also found this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45390/378998