# SVN diff for XML files in color to be emailed (Windows)

Tags: xml, windows, svn, diff

I'm trying to create something in which a SVN diff is performed on a series of XML files, and the results are emailed to a set of users.  However, I want the diff to be colorized according to the differences, along with color coding for the XML tags/attributes, etc as well.  This would be on the Windows platform.  Is this possible?

I did find a post on this ([Convert raw diff file to colorized html output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827862/convert-raw-diff-file-to-colorized-html-output)), but the python script suggested ended up having a lot of deprecated APIs used.  Plus I'm hoping perhaps since 2011, there's a better solution available.

Anybody have any ideas on this?