# ClearCase diff in HTML

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

I am trying to build a simple application that creates a diff of the checked-in source code and its previous version and send it as mail to the list of subscribers.

I am stuck with the part where I need to generate the "diff" of the current version and the previous version in HTML format so that I can easily mail it.

Is there any way to do it using ClearCase tools. If so please guide me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`cleartool diff`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm) and [`cleardiff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987629/6309), it seems you will need to process the `cleartool` command output in order to generate an html page.

For that, you could [consider `diff2html.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987629/6309) to create a side-by-side diff in a static html page from an unified diff input. (and [`cleartool diff` can produce a unified diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149187/6309))
Or [consider `cdiff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061886/6309).